# Real-time listening with MySQL server in AWS RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-rds, real-time

I want to create a MySQL instance on AWS RDS and provision a RDS proxy with it for handling lambda requests against the API calls through the API Gateway. I am quite new to AWS and this is the solution I found on the internet on how to best run a MySQL database on AWS. Please do correct me if this is wrong or I should try something better instead.

So anyway this is my setup I wish to carry on. I suspect that fetching data and performing CRUD operations through this will be easy. But I wonder how can I create WebSockets in RDS for a real-time chat feature in my application? Please guide me on how should I achieve this as I have not found any articles regarding this on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: "create WebSockets in RDS " - what do you mean exactly by this? How do you do it on local workstation?

Comment: @Marcin I am sorry if I am wrong here, but what I am actually looking for here is how to achieve a real-time chat feature with RDS. Websockets were something I used with API gateway to listen to any database changes, so I assumed that is how one would do in RDS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use AWS API Gateway to create Websocket service not AWS RDS. Please check this [resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html).

RDS Proxy is one of the way to manage connections. Another solution is AWS Aurora Serverless but you need connect to database within [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-working-with-amazon-aurora-serverless/).

Maybe you can consider use [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-websockets-example) or [chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice/blob/8df8b59aa759292ec065dae54a074731b11fa28e/docs/source/topics/websockets.rst) to make things easier.

If you want to invoke an AWS lambda function in your query, you can call [lambda_sync or lambda async function](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html).

Comment: So how can I set a trigger whenever a new row is added to my database so that the UI of my application changes in real-time? Is this possible with aurora?

Comment: @miraquee Yes it is possible. I updated answer, please check the last link for it.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for